# ExoPlayer play the file from cache / offline after downloading

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer, exoplayer

I'm using ExoPlayer and I have a file which must auto play after finishing movie play from top again.
I used LoopingMediaSource but here is the problem every time that movie start from the beginning it start download the file again but I expect after the first time movie display offline 
here is my custom CacheDataSourceFactory class

```
public class CacheDataSourceFactory implements DataSource.Factory {
private final Context context;
private final DefaultDataSourceFactory defaultDatasourceFactory;
private final long maxFileSize, maxCacheSize;
public static CacheDataSourceFactory cacheDataSourceFactory;
SimpleCache simpleCache;
public static CacheDataSourceFactory getInstance(Context context, long maxCacheSize, long maxFileSize) {
    if (cacheDataSourceFactory==null) {
        cacheDataSourceFactory = new CacheDataSourceFactory(context , maxCacheSize , maxFileSize);
    }
    return cacheDataSourceFactory;
}

private CacheDataSourceFactory(Context context, long maxCacheSize, long maxFileSize) {
    super();
    this.context = context;
    this.maxCacheSize = maxCacheSize;
    this.maxFileSize = maxFileSize;
    String userAgent = Util.getUserAgent(context, context.getString(R.string.app_name));
    DefaultBandwidthMeter bandwidthMeter = new DefaultBandwidthMeter();
    defaultDatasourceFactory = new DefaultDataSourceFactory(this.context,
            bandwidthMeter,
            new DefaultHttpDataSourceFactory(userAgent, bandwidthMeter));
    LeastRecentlyUsedCacheEvictor evictor = new LeastRecentlyUsedCacheEvictor(maxCacheSize);
    simpleCache = new SimpleCache(new File(context.getCacheDir(), "media"), evictor);

}

@Override
public DataSource createDataSource() {
    return new CacheDataSource(simpleCache, defaultDatasourceFactory.createDataSource(),
            new FileDataSource(), new CacheDataSink(simpleCache, maxFileSize),
            CacheDataSource.FLAG_BLOCK_ON_CACHE | CacheDataSource.FLAG_IGNORE_CACHE_ON_ERROR, null);
}

}
```

and here is my exo player code

```
defaultBandwidthMeter = new DefaultBandwidthMeter();
        BandwidthMeter bandwidthMeter = new DefaultBandwidthMeter();
        TrackSelection.Factory videoTrackSelectionFactory =
                new AdaptiveTrackSelection.Factory(bandwidthMeter);
        TrackSelector trackSelector = new DefaultTrackSelector(videoTrackSelectionFactory);
        LoadControl loadControl = new DefaultLoadControl();

        player = ExoPlayerFactory.newSimpleInstance(context, trackSelector, loadControl);
        DefaultExtractorsFactory extractorsFactory = new DefaultExtractorsFactory();
        dataSourceFactory = new DefaultDataSourceFactory(context,
                Util.getUserAgent(context, context.getResources().getString(R.string.app_name)), defaultBandwidthMeter);
        MediaSource mediaSource =
                new ExtractorMediaSource(
                        Uri.parse(banner.getImagePath()),
                        CacheDataSourceFactory.getInstance(context, 100 * 1024 * 1024, 10 * 1024 * 1024), extractorsFactory, null, null);

        holder.player_view.hideController();


            LoopingMediaSource loopingSource = new LoopingMediaSource(mediaSource);
            player.prepare(loopingSource, false, false);


            player.setPlayWhenReady(true);
```

Comment: check the file already got downloaded

Comment: @ManojPerumarath how ?

Comment: aren't you playing from a url?

Comment: banner.getImagePath() is my url @ManojPerumarath

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once the download is complete you need to save this url and it's download state in your mobile db

```
//if(check already downloaded then execute this
dataSourceFactory = new CacheDataSourceFactory(simpleCache , 
 DefaultHttpDataSourceFactory("test"));
mediaSource = new ExtractorMediaSource.Factory(dataSourceFactory)
    .createMediaSource(Uri.parse(yourUri));
player.prepare(mediaSource);
else {
// download /play  }
```

Comment: how to find out is downloaded or not